# Difference between joining two tables directly from remote database or joining two views that querying a table from remote database

Tags: sql-server, join, remote-server

I have three SQL Server DB in two separate servers.

- Database DB0 (Version 2014 SP1 Remote Database) in Server R
- Database DB1 (Version 2014 SP1 Remote Database) in Server R
- Database DB2 (Version 2012 SP3 Local Database) In Server L

There are 2 views T1 & T2 in Database DB1 that querying some tables in DB0 and I want to join it from Database DB2. (Noted: I am not supposed to direct querying DB0 due to some other restrictions)

I understand that I can use the following select statement to join it from Database L:

```
Select * from R.DB1.DBO.T1 T1 Left join R.DB2.DBO.T2 T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID;
```

However as I have created a view for both view in DB2 already.

```
Create view DB1_T1 as Select * from R.DB1.DBO.T1;
Create view DB1_T2 as Select * from R.DB1.DBO.T2;
```

I can actually simply joining this two views in DB2.

```
select * from DB1_T1 T1 left join DB1_T2 T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID;
```

So can I ask would there be any difference in terms of workload to the database between my first query and my second query:

```
1st: Select * from R.DB1.DBO.T1 T1 Left join R.DB2.DBO.T2 T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID;
2nd: select * from DB1_T1 T1 left join DB1_T2 T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID;
```

Comment: Views are simply stored queries to simplify complex queries. So no there will be no difference unless you created indexed views. Please see [this](https://www1.putlocker.digital/tv-series/alone-season-6/MUaVOGBy/sTviiokc/el91P361-watch-online-free.html)

Comment: Hi @CodingYoshi, Thanks for your response. But for the second query, would the join operation be performed in DB2 and data be transferred into the DB2 prior than the join operation? Or the entire query will still be executed in DB1 and DB1 will pass the entire result to DB2.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, BTW, I am not able to view your video as it was blocked by my company's proxy server. I will have a look tonight.